# Приветствие на сайте

Tags: javascript

Как сделать так, чтобы перейдя на главную страницу сайта, открывалось (со стороны) малое окошко (например, с приветствием). Как и где вставлять этот javascript-код в код страницы?

Answer (score 1):

"где вставлять этот javascript-код" - значения мало имеет. Для отображения вашего окошка в нужном месте, важнее параметры CSS прописаные для него. Для того, чтоб окошко появлялось только на главной, то не поверите, но можно: разместить скрипт, отвечающий за работу этого окошка, только на главной (если это у вас самостоятельный документ) или найти какой-то отличительный параметр/признак главной страницы и задать правило (напр., if ... else ...), которое будет включать этот скрипт на только главной и это не все варианты...